# kill qprocess with parent

Tags: c++, parent, kill, qprocess

This is the code to execute a command and return the output.
The problem is that if I kill the testProcess, "ping" keeps on going.
I tried also with

```
QObject *parent;
parent=new QObject;
myprocess *p;
p=new myprocess(parent);
```

sorry for my english

testProcess.h:

```
class myprocess : public QProcess{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myprocess( QObject *parent = 0 );
protected slots:
void readyOut();
void readyErr();
};
```

testProcess.cpp main:

```
myprocess *p;
p=new myprocess;

QObject::connect(p,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),p,SLOT(readyOut()));
QObject::connect(p,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),p,SLOT(readyErr()));

p->start("ping -t www.google.com");

p->waitForFinished(60000);

delete p;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your process to close when the application closes then you could connect to the core application `aboutToQuit()` signal.  It would look something like this

```
connect( QCoreApplication::instance(), SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), p, SLOT(kill()));
```

There is also a `terminate()` slot in the process that could be used, but I think `kill()` may be more appropriate in your situation.